# How to send parameters in javascript function used in HTA

Tags: javascript, hta

I am trying to pass filepath value to publish.bat.
Can some one please help me parameterize below JavaScript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <HTA:Application id="AppExecute" 
        ApplicationName="AppExecute"
        WindowState="maximize">
        <script language="JavaScript"><!--
        function myapp(filepath){
            var cmd = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            cmd.run("cmd /K CD C:\\publish & publish.bat C:\\publish\\prop\\lvl.Prop "&filepath)
            }
        --></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <font color=Blue><font size=3>Test Publisher
        <br>
        <Input type="text" name="filepath" title = "Do not change name of property files e.g. l2.ese">
        <input type="button" value="CMD" onclick="myapp(filepath)"><br>


        </form></center>
    </body>

</html>
```

I am getting Error:
[Script Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpfMm.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Post your attempt & exceptions if you got any. Avoid giving homework to others.

Comment: Sorry rookie developer here! I just provided error screen shot!

Comment: If a pathname contains spaces, it must be wrapped within double quotes.  `+` operator is used to concat strings in JS, `&` triggers syntax error. And `-->` is also a syntax error in JS, it needs to be `//-->` instead, or rather leave the HTML comment tags totally out from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several mistakes...
@Teemu explained some of them in the comment.
Then your buttons aren't properly enclosed within a **form** element. As I can see, there is only an ending tag for the form element.
After correcting that, you should change **onclick** event to:

```
onclick="myapp(this.form.filepath.value)"
```